# How to cleanly free a frame within a click event on a button on the frame?

Tags: delphi

I used to able to do this using plain delphi buttons:

In the First Frame I have (simplified)

```
procedure FirstFrame.ButtonClick(Sender: TObject)
Begin
  if TButton(Sender).ModalResult = mrOK then
    ChildFrame.DoOKStuff
  else
    ChildFrame.DoCancelStuff;
  ChildFrame.Free;
end;

procedure FirstFrame.ShowFranme;
begin
  ChildFrame := TFrameWithButtons.Create(Owner);
  ChildFrame.Parent := self;
  ChildFrame.OKButton.OnClick := ButtonClick;
  ChildFrame.CancelButton.OnClick := ButtonClick;
  ChildFrame.Visible := True;
end;
```

In the Childframe I do nothing to process the button click... the button click is already set to return control to the First Frame.

With some third Party buttons this occasionally causes an AV.
I understand why - at some point in the 3rd party code processing returns to a now freed frame or button BUT the called code is in the first frame... Annoyingly it just works 99.99% of the time :)

There is no Release procedure for frames.

So my question is what is the correct way to handle this situation?

Using both Delphi 6 and Delphi 2009.

Comment: How about reprocucing TCutsomForm.Release behaviour in your frame?

Comment: Assuming `ChildFrame` is a field of `FirstFrame`, you should probably call `FreeAndNil(ChildFrame)` instead of `ChildFrame.Free`. It would probably have the side effect of working 0% of the time after... but even if it works 99% of the time right now, it might not always give the correct result.

Comment: Apologies to the answer posters - I have not returned to this due to other pressures - but it's looks like CMRelease :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
type
  TFrameWithButtons = class(TFrame)
    ...
    procedure CMRelease(var Message: TMessage); message CM_RELEASE;
    ...
  end;

procedure TFrameWithButtons.CMRelease(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  Free;
end;

procedure FirstFrame.ButtonClick(Sender: TObject)
Begin
  if TButton(Sender).ModalResult = mrOK then
    ChildFrame.DoOKStuff
  else
    ChildFrame.DoCancelStuff;
  PostMessage(ChildFrame.Handle, CM_RELEASE, 0, 0);
end;
```

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at how `TCustomForm.Release` is implemented.  It's pretty simple: it posts a message to the Windows message queue, which when processed causes the form to free itself.  That shouldn't be too difficult to implement in your own code.